# php/css/wordpress issues with banner

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I'm having the following problem. Im using wordpress for my new website but i got a issue with my banner picutre. The picture is 150x1020 but for some reason it stays really smal and wont fill in the full width of the website. I've already been trying to add css in the css editor but no results till now. I use the Vantage theme on wordpress. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FUjXX.png). Can someone help me with this issue?

```js
<?php
/**
 * Part Name: Default Masthead
 */
?>
<header id="masthead" class="site-header" role="banner">

 <div class="hgroup full-container <?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'sidebar-masthead' ) ) echo 'masthead-sidebar' ?>">

  <?php if ( !is_active_sidebar( 'sidebar-masthead' ) ) : ?>

   <a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ); ?>" rel="home" class="logo"><?php vantage_display_logo(); ?></a>
   <?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'sidebar-header' ) ) : ?>

    <div id="header-sidebar" <?php if ( siteorigin_setting( 'logo_no_widget_overlay' ) ) echo 'class="no-logo-overlay"' ?>>
     <?php
     // Display the header area sidebar, and tell mobile navigation that we can use menus in here
     add_filter( 'siteorigin_mobilenav_is_valid', '__return_true' );
     dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-header' );
     remove_filter( 'siteorigin_mobilenav_is_valid', '__return_true' );
     ?>
    </div>

   <?php else : ?>

    <div class="support-text">
     <?php do_action( 'vantage_support_text' ); ?>
    </div>

   <?php endif; ?>

  <?php else : ?>

   <?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'sidebar-masthead' ) ) : ?>
    <div id="masthead-widgets" class="full-container">
     <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-masthead' ); ?>
    </div>
   <?php endif; ?>

  <?php endif; ?>

 </div><!-- .hgroup.full-container -->

 <?php get_template_part( 'parts/menu', apply_filters( 'vantage_menu_type', siteorigin_setting( 'layout_menu' ) ) ); ?>

</header><!-- #masthead .site-header -->
```

```css
#page-wrapper {
  padding-top: 20px;
  -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 1080px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.layout-full #page-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.layout-full #page-wrapper .full-container {
  max-width: 1080px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  position: relative;
}
@media (max-width: 1080px) {
  .responsive.layout-boxed #page-wrapper {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  .responsive.layout-boxed #colophon {
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }
}
#masthead {
  background: #fcfcfc;
  padding: 0 35px 0 35px;
  -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  zoom: 1;
}
#masthead:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
}
#masthead:after {
  content: '';
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
#masthead h1 {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
}
#masthead h1.logo-title {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
#masthead .hgroup {
  zoom: 1;
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 45px;
  padding-bottom: 45px;
}
#masthead .hgroup:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
}
#masthead .hgroup:after {
  content: '';
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
#masthead .hgroup a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
#masthead .hgroup h1 {
  color: #666666;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 36px;
  line-height: 1em;
}
#masthead .hgroup .logo {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  max-width: 100%;
}
#masthead .hgroup .logo img {
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
#masthead .hgroup .support-text {
  line-height: 1.2em;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -0.6em;
  color: #4b4b4b;
  font-style: italic;
  max-width: 50%;
}
#masthead .hgroup #header-sidebar {
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  /* Center align layout. Based on old CSS3 spec, so update when new spec is available and supported */
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  -moz-box-pack: center;
  -moz-box-align: center;
  display: -moz-box;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: box;
  box-pack: center;
  box-align: center;
}
#masthead .hgroup #header-sidebar aside.widget {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  margin-right: 25px;
}
#masthead .hgroup #header-sidebar aside.widget:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}
#masthead .hgroup #header-sidebar .widget-title {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
#masthead.masthead-logo-in-menu .main-navigation {
  zoom: 1;
}
#masthead.masthead-logo-in-menu .main-navigation:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
}
#masthead.masthead-logo-in-menu .main-navigation:after {
  content: '';
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
#masthead.masthead-logo-in-menu .logo {
  float: left;
  padding: 10px 0;
  margin-right: 15px;
}
#masthead.masthead-logo-in-menu .logo > * {
  display: block;
}
#masthead.masthead-logo-in-menu .logo > img {
  max-height: 33px;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
}
#masthead.masthead-logo-in-menu .logo > img.logo-no-height-constrain {
  max-height: none;
}
#masthead.masthead-logo-in-menu .logo > h1 {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 100;
  padding: 7px 15px;
}
.layout-boxed #masthead.masthead-logo-in-menu img.logo {
  margin-left: 25px;
}
```

Comment: I would change your code to use a background image, but if you want to use it like this, you would need to set #masthead .hgroup .logo img to 100% width. Might need to use #masthead .hgroup .logo img{width:100%!important;}

Answer (score 0):

For that theme you would need this.

```
#masthead .hgroup .logo {
    max-width: 100%;
    float: none;
}
#masthead .hgroup .logo img {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: How do i need to add it. Just in de extra css?
Im also using:
header#masthead .hgroup {
padding-bottom: 0px !important;
padding-top: 0px !important;
}

Comment: Yes, I would add it to your extra css, if the theme has a custom css theme options add it there, otherwise you should create a child theme, and add it to the child themes css file.

Comment: added them with !important but nothing happens